# Prefer algorithms to hand-written loops?

Tags: c++, algorithms

Which of the following to you find more readable? The hand-written loop:

```
for (std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    bar.process(*it);
}
```

Or the algorithm invocation:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <functional>

std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
              std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref(&Bar::process), bar));
```

I wonder if `std::for_each` is really worth it, given such a simple example already requires so much code.

What are your thoughts on this matter?

Comment: For C++, the answer is pretty obvious. But in other languages, both are about equal (e.g. Python: `map(bar.process, vec)`, although map for side effects is discouraged and list comprehensions/generator expressions are recommended over map).

Comment: And then there is also `BOOST_FOREACH` ...

Comment: So, the item in the effective STL did not convince you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135129/should-one-prefer-stl-algorithms-over-hand-rolled-loops

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There's a reason that lambdas were introduced, and it's because even the Standard Commitee recognizes that the second form sucks. Use the first form, until you get C++0x and lambda support.

Comment: The same reasoning can be used to justify the second form: the Standard Committee recognized that it was so much superior that they introduced lambdas to make it even better. :-p (+1 nevertheless)

Comment: I don;t think the second for is that bad. But it can be better. For example you deliberately made the Bar object harder to use by not adding operator(). By using this it greatly simplifies the call point in the loop and makes the code tidy.

Comment: Note: lambda support was added because of two major complaints. 1) The standard boilerplate needed to pass parameters to functors. 2) Not having the code at the call point. Your code satisfies neither of these as you are just calling a method. So 1) no extra code for passing parameters 2) The code is already not at the call point so lambda will not improve the code maintainability. So yes lambda are a great addition. This is not a good argument for them.

Answer (score 9):

Always use the variant that describes best **what** you intend to do. That is

> For each element `x` in `vec`, do `bar.process(x)`.

#### Now, let's examine the examples:

```
std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(),
              std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref(&Bar::process), bar));
```

We have a `for_each` there, too - *yippeh*. We have the `[begin; end)` range we want to operate on.

In principle, the algorithm was much more explicit and thus preferrable over any hand-written implementation. **But then** ... Binders? Memfun? Basically C++ interna of how to get hold of a member function? For my task, **I don't care** about them! Neither do I want to suffer from this verbose, creepy syntax.

#### Now the other possibility:

```
for (std::vector<Foo>::const_iterator it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it)
{
    bar.process(*it);
}
```

Granted, this is a common pattern to recognize, but ... creating iterators, looping, incrementing, dereferencing. These too are all things *I don't care* for in order to get my task done.

Admittedly, it looks waay better than the first solution (at least, the loop *body* is flexible and quite explicit), but still, it's not really *that* great. We'll use this one if we had no better possibility, but maybe we have ...

#### A better way?

Now back to `for_each`. Wouldn't it be great to literally say `for_each` **and** be flexible in the operation that is to be done, too? Fortunately, since C++0x lambdas, we are

```
for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), [&](const Foo& x) { bar.process(x); })
```

Now that we've found an abstract, generic solution to many related situations, it's worth noting that in this particular case, there is an absolute #1 [favorite](http://live.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/doc/html/foreach.html):

```
foreach(const Foo& x, vec) bar.process(x);
```

It really can't get much clearer than that. Thankfully, C++0x get's a similar syntax *built-in*!

Comment: Said "similar syntax" being `for (const Foo& x : vec) bar.process(x);`, or using `const auto&` if you like.

Comment: `const auto&` is possible? Didn't know that - great info!

Answer (score 8):

Because this is so unreadable?

```
for (unsigned int i=0;i<vec.size();i++) {
{
    bar.process(vec[i]);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason it says "censored" where I believe your code should be.

Comment: Your code gives a compiler warning, because comparing an `int` with a `size_t` is dangerous. Also, indexing doesn't work with every container, for example `std::set`.

Comment: This code will only work for containers with an indexing operator, of which there are few. It ties the algorithm down unnessarily - what if a map<> would suit better? The original for loop and for_each would be unaffected.

Comment: And how many times do you design code for a vector and then decide to swap it for a map? As if designing for that was the languages priority.

Comment: Iterating over collections by index is discouraged because some collections have poor performance on indexing, whereas all collections behave nicely when using an iterator.

Comment: You're right: it does read badly. (a) not using the proper `size_type`, (b) using post-increment like every other unthinking C/C++ example out there, (c) tying the user into an indexing container when they might want to change later. It's not about "the languages priority"; users can write generic code (at least now, with `auto` & lambdas) so that that *their* life is easier if they change the container type later. Which I'm doing right now, changing a `vector` to a `set`, so I can speak from experience; had I written more generic code to start with,  I would've had considerably less work now.

Answer (score 3):

in general, the first form is readable by pretty much anyone that knows what a for-loop is, no matter wat background they have.

also in general, the second one is not that readable at all: easy enough figuring what for_each is doing, but if you've never seen `std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref` I can imagine it's hard to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, even with C++0x, I am not sure `for_each` will get much love.

```
for(Foo& foo: vec) { bar.process(foo); }
```

Is way more readable.

The one thing I dislike about algorithms (in C++) is them reasoning on iterators, makes for very verbose statements.

Answer (score 2):

If you had written bar as a functor then it would be a lot simpler:

```
// custom functor
class Bar
{    public: void operator()(Foo& value) { /* STUFF */ }
};


std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), Bar());
```

Here the code is quite readable.

Comment: Its quite readable aside from the fact that you just wrote a functor.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3018676/140719) for why I think this code is worse.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer the latter because it's neat and clean. It's actually part of many other language but in C++, it's part of library. It's not really matters.

Answer (score 0):

Now this issue actually is not specific to C++, I would claim.

The thing is, passing some functor into yet another function is **not meant to replace loops**.
It is supposed to simplify certain patterns, that become very natural with functional programming, such as [visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) and [observer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), just to name two, that come to my mind immediately.
In languages that lack first order functions (Java probably is the best example), such approaches always require implementing some given interface, which is quite verbous and redundant.

A common use I see a lot in other languages would be:

```
someCollection.forEach(someUnaryFunctor);
```

The advantage of this is, that you need not know how `someCollection` is actually implemented or what `someUnaryFunctor` does. All you need to know is, that its `forEach` method will iterate all of the collection's elements, passing them to the given function.

Personally, if you're in the position, to have all information about the data structure you want to iterate over and all information about what you want to do in every iteration step, then a functional approach is overcomplicating things, especially in a language, where this is appearently quite tedious.

Also, you should bear in mind, that the functional approach is slower, because you have a lot of calls, which come at a certain cost, that you don't have in a for loop.

Comment: _"Also, you should bear in mind, that the functional approach is slower, because you have a lot of calls, which come at a certain cost, that you don't have in a for loop."_? This statement is unsupported. The functional approach is not necessarily slower, especially since there may be optimizations under the hood. And even if you completely understand your loop, it will probably look cleaner in its more abstract form.

Comment: @Andres F: So this looks cleaner? `std::for_each(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::bind1st(std::mem_fun_ref(&Bar::process), bar));` And it is either slower at runtime or compile time (if you're lucky). I don't see why replacing flow control structures with function calls makes code better. About any alternative presented here is more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that `for_each` isn't really an algorithm, it is just a different (and usually inferior way) to write a hand written loop. from this perspective it should be the least used standard algorithm, and yes you probably might as well use a for loop. however the advice in the title still stands as there are several standard algorithms tailored to more specifc uses.

Where there is an algorithm that more tightly does what you want then yes you should prefer algorithms over hand written loops. obvious examples here are sorting with `sort` or `stable_sort` or searching with `lower_bound`, `upper_bound` or `equal_range`, but most of them have some situation in which they are preferable to use over a hand coded loop.

Answer (score 0):

For this small code snippet, both are equaly readable to me. In general, I find manual loops error-prone and prefer using algorithms, but it really depends on a concrete situation.